# MongoDb query searching

Tags: mongodb

I am stuck in a small mongodb problem.

I have created an array of objects.

I want to search a particular number inside the below describe book array.

How can I do it:

My mongoose model is:

```
bookNumbers: [
    {
      book: [],
    },
  ],
```

I have tried this below query:

```
const existingBook = await bookPaymentModel.findOne({
    "bookNumbers.book": bookNumber,
  });
```

I am getting the bookNumber from frontend ie. from the input field entered by the user.

Please help me with the query of mongodb that I need to use to search inside this array.

Syntax of the altas database:

Its working for this particular model:

```
ticketNumbers: Array (3)

  0: Object

    ticket: Array (1)

       0: 2142523
     _id: 65c77fce82f4e74a53fbecbv

  1: Object

    ticket: Array (1)
     
       0: 2142444
     _id: 65c9b1dfef2c61aed5f97e5c
```

But its not working for this:

```
bookNumbers: Array (1)

  0: Object

    book: Array (3)

        0: Array (4)

          0: 184567
          1: 184568
          2: 184569
          3: 184570


        1: Array (4)

          0: 184579
          1: 184580
          2: 184581
          3: 184582

      _id: 65cc75fa56f9f1217e37220a
```

The book array contains multiple arrays

I am saving like this for an existing user

```
const newBookOrder = await bookPaymentModel.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            userId,
          },
          {
            $addToSet: {
              bookNumbers: [{ book: books }],

              razorpay_payment_id: razorpay_payment_id,
              razorpay_order_id: razorpay_order_id,
              razorpay_signature: razorpay_signature,
            },

            $push: {
              amount: amount,
              isPaid: true,
            },
          }
     );
```

I have tried this below query:

```
const existingBook = await bookPaymentModel.findOne({ "bookNumbers.book": bookNumber, });

     if (existingBook) {
        return next(
          errorHandler(
            404,
            "You have already bought this Ticket Number. Please choose another ticket number"
          )
        );
      }
```

I want add a validation:

If a particular number is already present in the database I want to return an error.

But its still getting saved in the database although it is already present in this particular collection ie. bookNumbers

I want it should not be saved when its already present.

I am not able to find where i did the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with the schema you have made. If you are only storing one field in bookNumbers that is book, then it shouldn't be an array, it should be an object. So your schema should look like

```
 bookNumbers: {
    book: [],
 },
```

You can search an item from an array using `$in` method. For your scenario, you can write the query as

```
const existingBook = await bookPaymentModel.findOne({
    "bookNumbers.book": {$in: [bookNumber]} ,
  });
```

[Search an item from array](https://sparkbyexamples.com/mongodb/mongodb-find-document-with-an-array-that-contains-a-specific-value/)

Comment: Sir, I don't want to save the array inside objects. I have wrote many lines of code. Where I displayed the arrays numbers using the map function. I am storing multiple arrays of fixed size of 12 numbers. When I am storing all the numbers in a single array it works fine the query works fine. But while I am in storing in multiple arrays that particular number is getting saved ie. I want it should not be saved. If you need more information please let me know

Comment: If you see the above description I provided. The ticketNumbers array stores single numbers. But the bookNumbers array storing additional multiple arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the updating. You need to update the array of `books` like this:

```
"$addToSet": {
    "bookNumbers.books": {
      "$each": books
    }
  }
```

Only if `books` is an array of integers. If only an integer is provided then `"bookNumbers.books": books`

Comment: Sir, I am storing fixed size of 12 numbers (integers) in every array. Only problem is finding the number in the database. If found the particular number comming from the front end should not be saved but a error message should be displayed to the user. Please help me if you need more information please let me know. If you see the above description I provided. The ticketNumbers array stores single numbers. But the bookNumbers array storing additional multiple arrays.

Comment: If you see the above description I provided. The ticketNumbers array stores single numbers. But the bookNumbers array storing additional multiple arrays.

Comment: ok, I just saw that your `bookNumbers.books` is array of arrays. Then do the following: `"bookNumbers.books": { $elemMatch: book }`